# How to resolve System.Type to System.Data.DbType?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

What is the best way to find [`System.Data.DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) enumeration value for Base Class Library types in System namespace?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A common way is to have a type map, with all supported types (*different connectors/providers supports different types*) explicitly mapped. Here is the type map for [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/4fb1ea29d490d13251b0135658ecc337aeb60cdb/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L169):

```
typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, DbType>();
typeMap[typeof(byte)] = DbType.Byte;
typeMap[typeof(sbyte)] = DbType.SByte;
typeMap[typeof(short)] = DbType.Int16;
typeMap[typeof(ushort)] = DbType.UInt16;
typeMap[typeof(int)] = DbType.Int32;
typeMap[typeof(uint)] = DbType.UInt32;
typeMap[typeof(long)] = DbType.Int64;
typeMap[typeof(ulong)] = DbType.UInt64;
typeMap[typeof(float)] = DbType.Single;
typeMap[typeof(double)] = DbType.Double;
typeMap[typeof(decimal)] = DbType.Decimal;
typeMap[typeof(bool)] = DbType.Boolean;
typeMap[typeof(string)] = DbType.String;
typeMap[typeof(char)] = DbType.StringFixedLength;
typeMap[typeof(Guid)] = DbType.Guid;
typeMap[typeof(DateTime)] = DbType.DateTime;
typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
typeMap[typeof(byte[])] = DbType.Binary;
typeMap[typeof(byte?)] = DbType.Byte;
typeMap[typeof(sbyte?)] = DbType.SByte;
typeMap[typeof(short?)] = DbType.Int16;
typeMap[typeof(ushort?)] = DbType.UInt16;
typeMap[typeof(int?)] = DbType.Int32;
typeMap[typeof(uint?)] = DbType.UInt32;
typeMap[typeof(long?)] = DbType.Int64;
typeMap[typeof(ulong?)] = DbType.UInt64;
typeMap[typeof(float?)] = DbType.Single;
typeMap[typeof(double?)] = DbType.Double;
typeMap[typeof(decimal?)] = DbType.Decimal;
typeMap[typeof(bool?)] = DbType.Boolean;
typeMap[typeof(char?)] = DbType.StringFixedLength;
typeMap[typeof(Guid?)] = DbType.Guid;
typeMap[typeof(DateTime?)] = DbType.DateTime;
typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset?)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
typeMap[typeof(System.Data.Linq.Binary)] = DbType.Binary;
```

To get a relevant DbType, all you need to do is:

```
var type = typeMap[typeof(string)]; // returns DbType.String
```

Comment: This looks good for me. I think there's no real need for me in Nullable versions, since `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` and `Type.GetGenericArguments` would help resolving Nullable value and underlying type.

Answer (score 18):

You can convert `TypeCode` to `DbType` using method `ConvertTypeCodeToDbType` in `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter` class: [Parameter.ConvertTypeCodeToDbType Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.converttypecodetodbtype(v=vs.110).aspx).
To get `TypeCode` you can use method `Type.GetTypeCode(Type type)`.

Comment: Why on earth this is on `System.Web`?

Answer (score 11):

You look at the documentation - [SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

The mappings for other providers are also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e5xt97a.aspx).

These give you enough information to write a converter.

Comment: But is there provider-agnostic way?

Comment: @Mike - I can't imagine there would be. The different databases and providers are implemented in different ways. The closest you can get it to find the most common mappings as documented and use them in a common class.

Comment: I understand. I just wonder why is there DbType in Framework? Its values closely resemble BCL types so I thought there should be a default mapping.

Comment: @Mike - No default mappings. `DbType` is there to represent all databases, as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is old question which is already answered, but there is easier way by using `SqlParameter`, which already has this logic implemented.
This is specific for **SqlServer**, but the providers for **Postgre**, **MySql** .. etc have corresponding implementations.

Here is a complete function which handles **non-nullable, nullable primitive types**, **decimal** and **string**

```
public static DbType GetDbType(Type runtimeType)
{
    var nonNullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(runtimeType);
    if (nonNullableType != null)
    {
        runtimeType = nonNullableType;
    }

    var templateValue = (Object)null;
    if (runtimeType.IsClass == false)
    {
        templateValue = Activator.CreateInstance(runtimeType);
    }

    var sqlParamter = new SqlParameter(parameterName: String.Empty, value: templateValue);

    return sqlParamter.DbType;
}
```

---

***How to get SqlParameter:***

For **SqlServer**, depending on your .netframework version you can find the `SqlParamter` type in **System.Data**, **System.Data.SqlClient nuget** and **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget**

---

***Source code for SqlParameter:***

The implementation of [SqlParameter](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/d6f2e29cda769e711988c64d3cb57eb5010a3e9c/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netfx/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs#L341) is using [this piece of code](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/d6f2e29cda769e711988c64d3cb57eb5010a3e9c/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netfx/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlEnums.cs#L351) which is pretty close to what the accepted answer is proposing.

Comment: Very dirty and inefficient, but very clever.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any automated logic, you should do the mapping yourself because those are different types and the .NET Framework cannot do this for you alone.

see here the whole mapping table: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) you can imagine that for Oracle, MySQL, sqLite and other engines there could be similar tables also depending on the .NET data provider / connect

Comment: I made this gist which contains the mapping table represented as a JavaScript array. It's handy for building your own C# lookup tables.
https://gist.github.com/wstabosz/7f59ca2518e0384c73f27902a7830040

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this here in case anyone else should happen to need the inverse of the Dapper lookup-table mentioned in alexn's answer. (it won't handle nullables)

```cs
Dictionary<DbType, Type> dbTypeMap = new Dictionary<DbType, Type>()
{
    { DbType.Binary, typeof(byte[])},
    { DbType.Boolean, typeof(bool)},
    { DbType.Byte, typeof(byte)},
    { DbType.DateTime, typeof(DateTime)},
    { DbType.DateTimeOffset, typeof(DateTimeOffset)},
    { DbType.Decimal, typeof(decimal)},
    { DbType.Double, typeof(double)},
    { DbType.Guid, typeof(Guid)},
    { DbType.Int16, typeof(short)},
    { DbType.Int32, typeof(int)},
    { DbType.Int64, typeof(long)},
    { DbType.SByte, typeof(sbyte)},
    { DbType.Single, typeof(float)},
    { DbType.String, typeof(string)},
    { DbType.StringFixedLength, typeof(char)},
    { DbType.UInt16, typeof(ushort)},
    { DbType.UInt32, typeof(uint)},
    { DbType.UInt64, typeof(ulong)}
};
```