# EntityType' is a variable but is used like a type when use the Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

i need to register all entity in `DbContext` .

i create a `extention` for register automatic all Entity with `Reflection` :

```
  public static void RegisterAllEntity<BaseType>(this DbModelBuilder builder, params Assembly[] assmblies)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> types = assmblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetExportedTypes())
            .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsPublic && typeof(BaseType).IsAssignableFrom(x));

        foreach (Type EntityType in types)
            builder.Entity<EntityType>();
    }
```

but it show me this error :

> EntityType' is a variable but is used like a type

in this line :

```
    foreach (Type EntityType in types)
            builder.Entity<EntityType>();
```

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???

Comment: You're mixing run time `Type` objects with compile time Typing, you need an overload of `Entity` which accepts a Type _object_.

Comment: @thisextendsthat Please guide me further. How should I do this?

Comment: You can find something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207451/x-is-a-variable-but-used-like-a-type-when-trying-to-cast

Comment: @RedaTaha i see that but it not answer me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I think you want to use [`DbModelBuilder.RegisterEntityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.registerentitytype?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbModelBuilder_RegisterEntityType_System_Type_) rather than `DbModelBuilder.Entity`. The documentation for the former says:

> This method is provided as a convenience to allow entity types to be registered dynamically without the need to use MakeGenericMethod in order to call the normal generic Entity method.

So rather than `builder.Entity<EntityType>();` you would instead use `builder.RegisterEntityType(EntityType);`

It is worth mentioning that often in situations like this there is a non-generic method that takes a `Type` object instead so if you find yourself in this situation with other software in the future check for that non-generic method with a `Type` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Generic Arguments need to be resolvable during compilation. You need to use reflection to call `Entity` method in such loop. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/7588582) anwser.

Example of usage

```
...
MethodInfo method = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(EntityType);
generic.Invoke(builder, null);
```

EDIT:

Also as Chris [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472336/entitytype-is-a-variable-but-is-used-like-a-type-when-use-the-reflection/55472507?noredirect=1#comment97655776_55472507), there is no need to use reflection because `DbModelBuilder` provide [RegisterEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.registerentitytype) method, which accept Type as argument, eg:

```
builder.RegisterEntityType(EntityType);
```

EDIT2: there's Chris' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472626/7588582)

Comment: No need to use reflection - DBModelBuilder provides a method (RegisterEntityType) that takes a `Type` as a parameter and explicitly says it exists to allow you to register things without he need to use `MakeGenericMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

You use EntityType as a variable in foreach cycle, and EntityType like type in `builder.Entity<EntityType>()`. Change variable name from EntityType to entityType for example so C# compiler could understand your code