# Converting primitive Type to OleDbType Enum

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, enums, oledb

I'm attempting to write a generic function for populating compound keys in a few tables of my database.

Unfortunately, I'm limited to using an `OleDbConnection` so can't make use of many of the niceties of the `SqlConnection` (and related) classes.

As part of this effort, I need to be able to convert generic system types (which will always be primitive `string`, `int` etc) to their `OleDbType` enum counterparts.

I've viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952142/how-to-resolve-system-type-to-system-data-dbtype) which has several suggestions in it: primarily, to use a class map. This approach would work fine however, it strikes me as strange that there would be no pre-built and pre-tested component of the .NET Framework that would do this significantly better than any code I would write would. I also dislike reinventing the wheel. The second approach suggested was to utilise the `Parameter.ConvertTypeToDbType` method in `System.Web` namespace (a stupid place to put it IMHO but I digress). This appears to work fine however, it yields a `DbType` enum rather than an `OleDbType` which I fear may cause compatibility issues.

My current attempt to utilise this approach looks like this:

```
OleDbParameter searchValueOne = new OleDbParameter("@searchValueOne", System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.ConvertTypeCodeToDbType(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T1))));
```

So my question would be, is there a similar built in function that provides an `OleDbType` as opposed to a `DbType` or is going with a `TypeMap` simply going to be the best approach?

Comment: `((int)DbType.Date)==((int)OleDbType.Double)` so you'd be correct that using your current code would be problematic. I don't think there's a built-in function since the preferred mapping may depend on the specific database you're connecting to whereas these enums are meant to be DB agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading comments and doing some further research it appears that a `TypeMap` is indeed the best option available.

Given that there are many cases where the different DB types map to the same `Type` (see `VarChar` and `BStr` amongst others), there are many different options available and which you take will depend on your database structure.

That being said, here's the class that I've come up with to perform this mapping, it should be a good starting point for anybody who wishes to try this in the future.

```
static class OleDbTypeMap
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type,OleDbType> TypeMap = new Dictionary<Type, OleDbType> {
        {typeof(string), OleDbType.VarChar },
        {typeof(long), OleDbType.BigInt },
        {typeof(byte[]), OleDbType.Binary },
        {typeof(bool), OleDbType.Boolean },
        {typeof(decimal), OleDbType.Decimal },
        {typeof(DateTime), OleDbType.Date },
        {typeof(TimeSpan), OleDbType.DBTime },
        {typeof(double), OleDbType.Double },
        {typeof(Exception),OleDbType.Error },
        {typeof(Guid), OleDbType.Guid },
        {typeof(int), OleDbType.Integer },
        {typeof(float), OleDbType.Single },
        {typeof(short), OleDbType.SmallInt },
        {typeof(sbyte), OleDbType.TinyInt },
        {typeof(ulong), OleDbType.UnsignedBigInt },
        {typeof(uint), OleDbType.UnsignedInt },
        {typeof(ushort), OleDbType.UnsignedSmallInt },
        {typeof(byte), OleDbType.UnsignedTinyInt }
    };
    public static OleDbType GetType(Type type) => TypeMap[type];
}
```

This could be modified with a `GetType(OleDbType type)` overload which accesses a different dictionary containing the inverse of the first to make this bi-directional, however, I don't need this functionality so haven't implemented it myself.

My `OleDbParameter` line now looks like this:

```
OleDbParameter searchValueOne = new OleDbParameter("@searchValueOne", OleDbTypeMap.GetType(typeof(T1)));
```

Which is much neater than before.

Comment: Consider using OleDbType.VarWChar to support Unicode for type string (in fact you SHOULD do that).